What is the purpose of tail -f /dev/null, usually at the end of scripts?
Before you light your torches:

I know what /dev/null is
I know how I/O redirection works in shell commands
I know what tail and -f flag does

However, I cannot grasp the reason for using the following:
tail -f /dev/null

This command is often found at the end of server-side scripts or, as it happened to me recently, in Docker containers (CMD ['sh', '-c', 'echo "The app is running!" && tail -f /dev/null']).
By knowing what I listed above, I would expect the output of tail to be a blank screen, forever, since no I/O to /dev/null is ever exposed to any program - trying the command in the shell does exactly that.
I can only think that this is a fancy way of Press CTRL-C to terminate.
But is there any non-obvious purpose to it other than that?
Can you achieve the same with other commands? I could think of read anyKey for the popular Press any key to continue... prompt.

The purpose is to not quit. It serves the same purpose as sleep infinity, but more portable when infinity is not understood by sleep.

Thanks. Is there any particular reason you would want your script not to quit? Background tasks maybe?

hi want your script not to quit? Ask the author, not us. There is no generic answer. Ask the person who wrote the command you found.  I do not like "maybe", I like to be specific. The person who wrote the command will be more specific than our  guesses. Background tasks maybe? Yes.
